# Access multiple exports to existing Excel workbook

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm using Access 2013 and exporting data to an exisitng Excel 2010 workbook.  I'm using the following code (passing the query, worksheet and excel filename).  It all works great:

```
Public Function SendTQ2XLWbSheetSizeRange(strTQName As String, strSheetName As String, strFilePath As String)
' strTQName is the name of the table or query you want to send to Excel
' strSheetName is the name of the sheet you want to send it to
' strFilePath is the name and path of the file you want to send this data into.

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim ApXL As Object
    Dim xlWBk As Object
    Dim xlWSh As Object
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim strPath As String
    Const xlCenter As Long = -4108
    Const xlBottom As Long = -4107
    On Error GoTo err_handler

    strPath = strFilePath

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strTQName)

    Set ApXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set xlWBk = ApXL.Workbooks.Open(strPath)

    ApXL.Visible = True

    Set xlWSh = xlWBk.Worksheets(strSheetName)

    xlWSh.Activate

    xlWSh.Range("A5").Select

    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        ApXL.ActiveCell = fld.Name
        ApXL.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next

    rst.MoveFirst

    xlWSh.Range("A6").CopyFromRecordset rst

    xlWSh.Range("1:1").Select
    ' This is included to show some of what you can do about formatting.  You can comment out or delete
    ' any of this that you don't want to use in your own export.
    With ApXL.Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
    End With

    ApXL.Selection.Font.Bold = True

    With ApXL.Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .MergeCells = False
    End With

    ' selects all of the cells
    ApXL.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select

    ' does the "autofit" for all columns
    ApXL.ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ' selects the first cell to unselect all cells
    xlWSh.Range("A1").Select

    rst.Close

    Set rst = Nothing

Exit_SendTQ2XLWbSheet:
    Exit Function

err_handler:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_SendTQ2XLWbSheet
End Function
```

Now I have a requirement to export another query to a different workbook within the same Excel file.  The problem is the code above opens the Excel file, so if I then call the procedure again, it then opens an additional read-only copy of the Excel.  How do I get around this?  It total I will need to perform 3 exports to 3 different worksheets within 1 Excel file.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this code that your wrote? Do you understand the what `Set ApXL` and `Set xlWBk` are doing?   You say "different workbook within the same Excel file." --- The same Excel Application, you mean?

Comment: You can 1. move creating the excel application outside your loop, whatever it may be. 2. close excel and close the file (workbook) each time. 3. use an if statement that detects existing excel applications and loop through them and then loop through their open files in order to find if it matches the file path that you are currently trying to open. --- I prefer 3. and assume that there is only one excel open, but I can't seem to find the code online. Basically you need to "attach to an existing excel process in vba"

Answer (score 0):

I'd use three procedures.  The first just identifies which file to open and which query goes on which sheet.

This will place Query1 on Sheet1, Query2 on Sheet2.  It uses a `ParamArray` so you can add as many sheet/query pairs as you like:

```
Public Sub ProcessExcel()

    SendToExcel "<full path to Excel file>", "Sheet1", "Query1", "Sheet2", "Query2"

End Sub
```

The second procedure sets a reference to Excel, opens the workbook and then starts processing the ParamArray.  The sheet name is used to create a reference to the actual sheet which is then passed to the next procedure.

```
Public Sub SendToExcel(sFilePath As String, ParamArray ShtQry() As Variant)

    Dim oXL As Object   'Ref to Excel.
    Dim oWB As Object   'Ref to workbook.
    Dim x As Long       'General counter

    'Get or create reference to Excel.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo Err_Handle
        Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo Err_Handle

    Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)

    For x = LBound(ShtQry) To UBound(ShtQry) Step 2
        SendTQ2XLWbSheetSizeRange oWB.worksheets(CStr(ShtQry(x))), CStr(ShtQry(x + 1))
    Next x

Exit Sub

Err_Handle:

End Sub
```

The final procedure opens the recordset and pastes everything onto the correct sheet:

```
Public Sub SendTQ2XLWbSheetSizeRange(oWrkSht As Object, sTQName As String)
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim x As Long

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sTQName)

    With oWrkSht
        'Place field headings.
        For x = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
            .cells(5, x + 1) = rst.Fields(x).Name
        Next x
        'Place values.
        .Range("A6").CopyFromRecordset rst
    End With

    rst.Close

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

I've missed out plenty of error checks in the code - ensure the sheet exists, that the array holds sheet/query pairs and lots I haven't even considered.

**Note:**  Not a single `Select` or `Activate` in sight - just reference the sheet.

Comment: Ah perfect, that `'Get or create reference to Excel.` is exactly the code I was looking for. I found it in the documentation [here, under using powerpoint...](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/2327/powerpoint-integration-through-vba/7636/the-basics-launching-powerpoint-from-vba#t=201704121343306834863)  

AFAIK it doesn't really work with people who have multiple excel instances open.

Comment: Snippets of code like that I have as their own functions and saved as .bas files - when starting a new project I just drag the files into my project and I'm good to go with a simple `Set oXL = CreateXL`.  With a good size bas library creating projects is just like shopping - I'll have one of them, one of them and one of them... bit of glue to stick it all together and job done. :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound right: 'export another query to a different workbook within the same Excel file'.  How about exporting the contents of different tables to one single Excel file, but placing the results of each table to a separate sheet in the same Excel file.  You can easily modify the code to export queries to separate Excel sheets, instead of exporting tables.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private Sub Command0_Click()

  Dim strFile As String
  Dim varItem As Variant

    strFile = InputBox("Designate the path and file name to export to...", "Export")

    If (strFile = vbNullString) Then Exit Sub

    For Each varItem In Me.List0.ItemsSelected
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transferType:=acExport, _
                                  spreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                                  tableName:=Me.List0.ItemData(varItem), _
                                  FileName:=strFile
    Next

    MsgBox "Process complete.", vbOKOnly, "Export"
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  Dim strTables As String
  Dim tdf As TableDef
  ' Reference: MS DAO 3.6
  ' Properties > All > Row Source Type = Value List
    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If (Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys") Then
            strTables = strTables & tdf.Name & ","
        End If
    Next
    strTables = Left(strTables, Len(strTables) - 1)

    Me.List0.RowSource = strTables
End Sub
```

Add a ListBox to a form, and a button on the same form, and run it that way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their kind words and suggestions.  I've gone with @Cody G. 2nd suggestions and just closed the excel file each time, so just adding

```
xlWBk.Close True

Set xlWBk = Nothing

ApXL.Quit

Set ApXL = Nothing
```

Each time.